# Beamer with csquotes.sty and \MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}

Tags: beamer, csquotes

When I try to load `csquotes` and use '\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}' I get a the following error message passed through by `latexmk`:

```
! Package csquotes Error: Invalid argument.

See the csquotes package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
```

The help tells me this:

```
Only single characters with category code 12 or 13 may be
allocated as active quotes. Numbers, punctuation marks, and
characters which are part of LaTeX's syntax or reserved
for a specific purpose are invalid.
```

The thing is I only get this problem with Beamer. Using the article class there is no error. Can I really not use those quotes as auto quotes?

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine with `beamer` just as it does with other classes. However, as with other classes, you need the unicode characters to be recognised. You have basically three choices:

- use XeLaTeX
- use LuaLaTeX
- add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Whichever option you choose, make sure the file is saved in UTF-8 encoding. Just as you would with any other class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Of course! I actually loaded `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` later in my code, but it has to come before.